# Scala: implicit lookup of type class instance for path-dependent type

Tags: scala, implicit, path-dependent-type

```
trait Encoder[From, To] {
  def encode(x: From): To
}
object Encoder {
  implicit val thingToString: Encoder[Thing, String] = new Encoder[Thing, String] {
    def encode(x: Thing): String = x.toString
  }
}

trait Config {
  type Repr
}
class MyConfig extends Config { type Repr = String }
//class ConcreteConfig { type Repr = String }

class Api[T](val config: Config) {
  def doSomething(value: T)(implicit encoder: Encoder[T, config.Repr]): Unit = {}
}

case class Thing(a: Int)

object Test extends App {
  import Encoder._

  val api = new Api[Thing](new MyConfig)
  api.doSomething(Thing(42))
}
```

The call to `api.doSomething` fails to compile:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: Encoder[Thing,Test.api.config.Repr]
```

If I change the signature of `class Api[T]`'s constructor so that it takes a `ConcreteConfig`, then the compiler can tell that `config.Repr == String` and the implicit lookup succeeds. But this wouldn't really work for my use case.

Is there any other way to guide the implicit lookup? Am I losing type info because I'm missing a type refinement or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>This can't be achieved since config.Repr is not a stable path.</del> The compiler can't determine that config.Repr = String, even though the runtime value of config is of type MyConfig.

This is going to work only if you can provide concrete config instance as a type parameter in Api, which will tell compiler what is the exact type of Repr:

```scala
class Api[T, C <: Config](val config: C) {
  def doSomething(value: T)(implicit encoder: Encoder[T, config.Repr]): Unit = {}
}

object Test extends App {
  import Encoder._

  val api = new Api[Thing, MyConfig](new MyConfig)
  api.doSomething(Thing(42))
}
```

Comment: `api.config.Repr` _is_ a stable path, though your second sentence is right.

Answer (score 0):

Infer types one step at a time. Also, I don't see any reason for using value-dependent types here (or, for that matter, anywhere; that's a different question though).

```scala
trait Encoder[From, To] {
  def encode(x: From): To
}
object Encoder {

  implicit val thingToString: Encoder[Thing, String] = new Encoder[Thing, String] {
    def encode(x: Thing): String = x.toString
  }
}

trait Config {
  type Repr
}
class MyConfig extends Config { type Repr = String }
// class ConcreteConfig { type Repr = String }

case class Api[T, C <: Config](val config: C) {
  def doSomething(value: T)(implicit encoder: Encoder[T, C#Repr]): Unit = ()
}

case class ApiFor[T]() {
  def withConfig[C <: Config](config: C): Api[T,C] = Api(config)
}

case class Thing(a: Int)

object Test extends App {
  import Encoder._

  val api = ApiFor[Thing] withConfig new MyConfig
  // compiles!
  api.doSomething(Thing(42))
}
```